# How to setup the jenkins build to test python web application?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I am new to jenkins and I wanted to do CI/CD pipeline using jenkins for my python web application. In order to run the python backend tests I need to install the requirements and setup a python environment for that. Installing the requirements need pip3 and python3 environment. I have gone through couple of articles regarding setting up a python virtual environment for jenkins , installing pip and so on, but nothing worked for me. It will be great if anyone could guide me in this regard.

Listing below the current script that I used,

```
   echo "****Starting CI/CD Pipeline****"
   PATH=$WORKSPACE/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   if [ ! -d "venv" ]; then
       virtualenv venv
   fi
      . venv/bin/activate
   echo "****Installing dependencies****"
   pip3 install -r backend/requirements.txt --download-cache=/tmp/$JOB_NAME
   echo "****Running backend tests****"
   python3 -m pytest backend/tests/*
```